# Android ActionBar - style error, but AppCompat added

Tags: android

I'm new to Android programming. I want to use Android Studio (I have the newest one, version 0.8.2), and style my Action Bar.

The Gradle throws the following error during the build process:

```
Error:Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

Here's my style.xml file:

```
<resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style
    name="AppTheme"
    parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/SocialExitActionBar</item>
</style>
<style
    name="SocialExitActionBar"
    parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tranparent</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

It's the same as the [Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html). In every question, I found, the answer was to add the appcompat Library. But I have the appcompat library added in my build.gradle file:

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.procode.socialexit"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}
```

Here's on pic: [image: The Project dependencies]
[link](http://snag.gy/mms41.jpg)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the `@android:style/` before each parent value.